# JsConfig<MyClass>.ExcludePropertyNames example, not working for me

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

Trying to exclude properties from a model from being included during serialization.

I am using the following syntax:

```
JsConfig<MyTestClass>.ExcludePropertyNames = new[] { "ShortDescription" };
```

Just after that I have the following:

```
            return     (from o in __someProvider.GetAll() select (new
                      {
                          o.Name,
                          o.ShortDescription
                          o.InsertDate
                      }).TranslateTo<MyTestClass>()).ToList()
```

However once result is returned from the method, it still contains "ShortDescription" field in the Json. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JsConfig<T>.ExcludePropertyNames` appears to be checked only once for each type, in a [static constructor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/TypeConfig.cs#L49) for `TypeConfig<T>`. Thus, if you are configuring `ExcludePropertyNames` in your service class, just before returning your response, it might be too late -- the TypeConfig properties may already be set up and cached for `MyTestClass`. I was able to reproduce this.

A more reliable alternative is to move all of your `JsConfig<T>` configuration to your `AppHost` setup code.

If you really do need to do this in your service class, e.g. if you are only conditionally excluding property names, then an alternative approach would be to ensure that `JsConfig.IncludeNullValues` is false (I believe it is by default) and in your service code set `ShortDescription` to null when appropriate.